# nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed While Fetching Data from API Call

Tags: swift, api

I'm trying to fetch weather forecast data using openweathermap API. So I write this -

> View Controller 
> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raf-wtag/32eb2d963fba31d325355cf642354715/raw/b8d7ee43258d8c5be826eab9b22322697d00ead9/FetchAPICall

The API Result I get in browser is -

> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raf-wtag/a36a5af3514fc81d92927959b8af92de/raw/d8fdc570490e5d1e7493d3092bd18b6b16bedf0c/API%2520Response

to fetch the api result and print it in the Xcode console. Here is my Model (as per the json response) -

> Model 
> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raf-wtag/54a6361291c1e8124d9b1a9d866ffc47/raw/f46a72c12cdedf8302401029b8980233bcef6711/FetchAPICallModel

I tried to run it in emulator but getting this error -

```
In fetching Data
Executed 1st Line
2021-03-24 12:03:21.521208+0600 FetechAPIData[2554:97850] [] 
     nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
Executed 2nd Line
```

So I think The message is printing for in fetchData() -

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
```

Additionally I've seen [this forum post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665599) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/jcx6j2/learning_swift_need_help_understanding_api_error/) said about it occurs in emulator but not in real device. Is it correct or Something I've to change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is happening only in the emulator. When I tried to test same app with Physical Device there is no such message.